# left aligning the conditional statement inside an array

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays

I have equations of the form

```
a = b + d     for i <= 4, j < 3
  = c         for i = 5
  = d - e + u for i > 5
```

I am writing them using the following code in latex:

```
\begin{equation} 
  a = \left\{
 \begin{array}{lr}
 b + d  & \mbox{for } i \le 4, j < 3 \\
 c & \mbox{for } i = 5 \\
 d - e + u & \mbox{for } i > 5
\end{array}
\right.
\label{eqn:simple_one} 
\end{equation}
```

But the problem is that the conditional statements starting with "for" are always right aligned and the output looks like this (with a left brace after the "=" sign, which i cannot draw :) ).

```
a = b + d     for i <= 4, j < 3
    c                 for i = 5
    d - e + u         for i > 5
```

I wanted to make the condtional part left aligned such that the words "for" come exactly one below the other. How can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are right aligned because you have `{array}{lr}`
 change that to `{array}{ll}` to left align both columns. But generally it is best not to use `array` for laying out whole equations, it is designed for matrices/arrays. Here I think the `amsmath` package and its `cases` environment would be better.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Maybe its also good to note the other cases environment if needed such as: `rcases` (used for a right-aligned brace), `dcases` (used for display-math inside of the `cases` environment, and others that maybe available.

Comment: For anyone using Lyx, this feature is hidden behind the "Rows & Columns" item in the context menu appearing upon right-clicking the cell in question (how to do it for the entire environment, I don't know yet). There's also a shortcut `Alt+M C L`, where L stands for _left_, M for _middle_ and R for _right_.

Answer (score 11):

using `amsmath` and `\cases` allows this to be accomplished with simpler coding:

```
\begin{equation} 
  a = \begin{cases}
 b + d  & \text{for $i \le 4$, $j < 3$} \\
 c & \text{for $i = 5$} \\
 d - e + u & \text{for $i > 5$}
\end{cases}
\label{eqn:simple_one} 
\end{equation}
```

with this result:

[image]

also note the use of `\text` instead of `\mbox`.  `\text` will produce the correct size whether it's used at the base level or in sub- or superscripts or limits.

Comment: I'd type `\text{for $i \le 4$, $j < 3$}`, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @egreg -- you're absolutely right.  updated in example.